# Choose container for DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

Is it possible to create a DialogFragment and change the default container?
I tried `DialogFragment.show(Transaction, ...)`and set the container there but then it tells me `Fragment already added`.
It's important that the DialogFragment behaves like a normal DialogFragment.

Edit: I think there are some misunderstandings. I said it should look "like a normal DialogFragment". What I mean is it should look like a normal AlertDialog.

Comment: add some more details like code,exception messages. and is "default container" relates to custom dialog view..?

Comment: It's a general question. I want to have a lockscreen on top of everything else. So I need to place my DialogFragments in a container, that lies underneath the lockscreencontainer layoutwise.

Comment: lock screen is widget to call it when screen locked we use getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);

Answer (score 1):

I think since a `DialogFragment` extends from a `Fragment`, you can use it as a normal `Fragment` wherever required. It should still implement all the `Fragment` lifecycle methods. However, I'm not sure if it overrides any of them for a special purpose.

Answer (score 1):

you can use dialogFragment like an ordinary fragment. have a look at this code from samples.
In this code it creates one dialogFragment and added it to the framlayout and also show it as a dialog when you press the button.

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Demonstrates the same fragment
            being shown as a dialog and embedded inside of an activity." />

    <Button android:id="@+id/show_dialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="show">
        <requestFocus />
    </Button>

    <View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inline_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Fragment embedded inside
        of the activity:" />

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/embedded"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:background="#ff303030"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the java code:

```
public class FragmentDialogOrActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_dialog_or_activity);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // First-time init; create fragment to embed in activity.

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
            ft.add(R.id.embedded, newFragment);
            ft.commit();

        }

        // Watch for button clicks.
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.show_dialog);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });
    }


    void showDialog() {
        // Create the fragment and show it as a dialog.
        DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }



    public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {
            return new MyDialogFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);
            View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
            ((TextView)tv).setText("This is an instance of MyDialogFragment");
            return v;
        }
    }

}
```

and for your error you can use below code:

```
public static void showMyDialogFragment(FragmentManager fm){

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = fm.findFragmentByTag("MyDialogFragment");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(ft, "MyDialogFragment");
}
```

as you noticed I changed the tag name so you can distinguish between dialog fragment and ordinary fragment added to your layout.

Comment: Look at my op edit. I mean it should look like an alertdialog. I think in your exmaple you just have one textView. No title, no dialog buttons. If you say DialogFagment.show, you can't pick the container. So this won't work.

Comment: when I use `MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment` that means it can be any thing you like. you can add button to the fragment layout create custom title and everything you could imagine. THIS IS JUST A SAMPLE, you can replace `R.layout.hello_world` by whatever you like.

Comment: So I have to gather all needed styles for my title and buttons to have it look like an AlertDialog?

Comment: you can do so and also can customize `AlertDialog` itself with provided functions.

Comment: To use the AlertDialog I would have to use onCreateDialog. onCreateDialog is only called when I use DialogFragment.show() and that means I can't embed my DialogFragment.

Answer (score 0):

here is example from [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        int mNum;

    /**
     * Create a new instance of MyDialogFragment, providing "num"
     * as an argument.
     */
    static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int num) {
        MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");

        // Pick a style based on the num.
        int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, theme = 0;
        switch ((mNum-1)%6) {
            case 1: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE; break;
            case 2: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME; break;
            case 3: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_INPUT; break;
            case 4: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
            case 5: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
            case 6: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE; break;
            case 7: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME; break;
            case 8: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
        }
        switch ((mNum-1)%6) {
            case 4: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo; break;
            case 5: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog; break;
            case 6: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light; break;
            case 7: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Panel; break;
            case 8: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light; break;
        }
        setStyle(style, theme);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // put here any view you want 
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ((TextView)tv).setText("Dialog #" + mNum + ": using style "
                + getNameForNum(mNum));

        // Watch for button clicks.
        Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.show);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // When button is clicked, call up to owning activity.
                ((FragmentDialog)getActivity()).showDialog();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}



void showDialog() {
    mStackLevel++;

    // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
    // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
    // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      // may you got error here 
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
     // remove fragment from stack will fix the problem 
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    // Create and show the dialog.
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```

if you want use it in alert buttons here is the code

```
public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
        MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .create();
    }
}
```

Comment: what about alertdialog buttons? Would I have to mimic the appearance in my layout?

Comment: no you can use it as you want , read documentation you will find example also about that , i will update answer also for you

Comment: This won't work. If you embed a DialogFragment, onCreateDialog won't be called. So either you can choose a container but can't have a native alertDialog, OR you can have a native AlertDialog, but can't embed it in your layout. Is this correct?

Comment: how sir it should be , have a look http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout , put any custom layout you want 
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))